# VSTS HttpBuildClient Update Definition Async throws type exception

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I'm trying to automate setting up build definitions.  In my process I need to update an existing definition.  I'm retrieving existing definitions just fine but when I go to update them I get the following exception:
`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: 'Expecting 'Process' to be of type 'T'.'`

it is being thrown when I call `await buildClient.UpdateDefinitionAsync(buildDef);`

Here is the full code in context:

```
public async void Test()
    {
        var buildClient = new BuildHttpClient(new Uri(VstsCollectionUrl),
            new VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential(_auth.AccessToken));

        var buildDef =
            (await buildClient.GetFullDefinitionsAsync(Guid.Parse("My GUID As String"))).FirstOrDefault(def => def.Repository.Name == "App Test");

        if (buildDef == default(BuildDefinition))
            return;

        var newRepoSettings = buildDef.Repository;
        newRepoSettings.Properties["skipSyncSource"] = "true";
        newRepoSettings.Properties["labelSources"] = "6";
        buildDef.Repository = newRepoSettings;
        buildDef.Path = @"\";



        await buildClient.UpdateDefinitionAsync(buildDef); //Error thrown here
}
```

Am I using the right function?  Am I not setting something that i'm not supposed to, or is this a bug in the API/SDK?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient  15.112.1. What's the version of package you used? What's the definition like? Provide the definition json data here.

Comment: I'm using the same version of the nuget package that you stated.  Also the build definition is the YAML definition and i'm not able to export that.  Is YAML definitions not yet supported.  I'm just trying to change those few repository settings not the 'tasks' themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update the package version to higher version (e.g. 15.131.0-preview).

The reason is that, with the old version, there aren’t the necessary property in BuildDefinition type, such as Process.

Comment: trying to update the nuget package throws this error:
`Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Common 15.112.1 constraint: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client (= 15.112.1)', 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Common.Contracts 16.118.0-preview constraint: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client (= 16.118.0-preview)'.   0 `

Comment: this is working by updating the the latest preview nuget packages (16.135.0-preview)  I was having issues including the dependencies b/c it looks as though the corresponding latest/preview nuget package for `microsoft.teamfoundation.distributedtask.common` hasn't been published publicly.  Still, accepting this answer.

Comment: it's a shame 18 months later that the BuildDefinition still lacks public accessor to the Process property - however you can still access it if you cast the object to dynamic...